# Обособление оборота "как с другом"

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, как

Оборот "как с другом" обособляется часто, но не всегда. Какова семантика этих вариантов, можно ли найти несложное решение этой задачи?

(1) Человек он был честный и смирный; я знал его с детства и обращался с ним как с другом (И. C. Тургенев).

(2) Государь обходился с ним как с другом, поверяя ему все тайны сердечные (Н. М. Карамзин).

(3) Я думала поговорить с вами как с другом, ― сказала она. [Н. Н. Златовратский.

(4)Позвольте говорить мне с вами, как с другом (П. Н. Врангель).

(5) Ради бога, поступайте в отношении меня, как с другом, столь крепко и беззаветно Вам преданным  (П. И. Чайковский).

(6) Говоря со мной, как с другом, мать всегда высылала мою сестрицу и запрещала мне рассказывать ей наши откровенные разговоры (С. Т. Аксаков).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это действительно очень сложные случаи постановки знаков. Чтобы не ошибиться, нужно чётко определить функцию оборота с *как* в конкретном предложении. Необходимо учитывать и структуру предложения (пример 5).

(1) Человек он был честный и смирный; я знал его с детства и обращался с ним как с другом (И. C. Тургенев). — **По-дружески. Кроме того, выражение *как с другом* входит в состав сказуемого.**

(2) Государь обходился с ним как с другом, поверяя ему все тайны сердечные (Н.М.Карамзин). — **Входит в состав сказуемого.** Деепричастный оборот относится ко всему сказуемому.

(3) Я думала поговорить с вами как с другом, ― сказала она. — **По-дружески.**

(4)Позвольте говорить мне с вами, как с другом (П. Н. Врангель). — **Неполное придаточное предложение. Ср.: ...*, как говорят с другом.***

(5) Ради бога, поступайте в отношении меня, как с другом, столь крепко и беззаветно Вам преданным (П. И. Чайковский). — **Придаточное сравнительное. Ср.: ..., *как поступают с другом, ...*** **Причастный оборот относится к слову** *другом*.

(6) Говоря со мной, как с другом, мать всегда высылала мою сестрицу и запрещала мне рассказывать ей наши откровенные разговоры (С. Т. Аксаков). — **Неполное придаточное. Ср.: ...,*как говорят с другом*,...**

Comment: Екатерина, вы совершенно справедливо указываете на грамматические особенности обособленных и необособленных оборотов. А как насчет семантики? Можно ли сказать, что мы здесь делаем выбор между тождеством со значением в качестве и сравнением.  (Это довольно редкий случай, когда их значения схожи).  Сравним (3) и (4). В предложении (3) они друзья или находятся в близких отношениях, но сейчас в разговоре она хотела бы услышать мнение друга (здесь тождество, в качестве). В предложении (4) они, скорее, не друзья, но он хотел б дружеской беседы - "как будто с другом". Это сравнение, но не тождество.

Comment: И вопрос: может ли деление на "тождество - сравнение" помочь решению задачи, как в думаете?

Comment: Вы, без сомнения,  правы:  семантика должна быть главным критерием при выборе знаков препинания в такого рода примерах. Деление на тождество и сравнение действительно помогает решению задачи. По сути, всё на этом делении и строится. Это база.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, здесь можно применить правило:  сравнительный оборот с союзом как характеризует предмет лишь с одной стороны ( запятая в этом случае не ставится).

В примерах же с запятой оборот можно заменить наречием.

Ради бога, поступайте в отношении меня, как с другом (по-дружески)
 Говоря со мной, как с другом( по-дружески).

У Розенталя такие примеры оговариваются.
См.[Сравнительный оборот, п.5, см. примечание](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147)

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. У Лопатина такие примеры:Я относился к нему как к брату — ‘он мне брат’. Я относился к нему, как к брату — ‘по-братски’, ‘он мне не брат’. Но выбор, как мне кажется зависит от контекста: если названы другие варианты, кроме брата, то это значение "в качестве". Если имеется в виду ПРИЗНАКОВЫЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ (искренне, с душой), то это сравнительный оборот, который обычно обособляется.

Comment: Вера, если честно, у Лопатина я не видел эти примеры. Вера, вы считаете, что, например, со словом друг такое значение невозможно?

Comment: Я думаю, что возможно, но с вполне конкретными  значениями: (1) Она относится к нему как к брату (не как к жениху или любимому человеку). (2) Она относится к нему,  как к брату (искренне, с доверием). В обоих случаях он ей не брат.

Comment: Да, Вера. Такое значение возможно. Только подумал. Он относится к нему как к брату (‘он мне брат’). Насколько вообще правильна такая трактовка? Мне кажется, так только можно сказать по отношению к человеку, кто тебе не брат. Что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: Ну да, я как раз писала об этом:В обоих случаях он ей не брат.

Comment: Интересно, из чего исходил Розенталь и его коллеги, когда писали правила?

Answer (score 2):

Некоторые наблюдения и вводы

1) Обычно значение ТОЖДЕСТВА характерно для тех случаев, когда выбирается  СТАТУС ЛИЦА: слуга, советчик, любимая девушка или друг:

он одновременно общался еще с одной девушкой, но только как с другом,

обращался с Белосельцевым как с другом, которого не нужно бояться,

отношения не только как с другом, но и лучшим советчиком,

обращаюсь с ним не только как с слугой, но и как с другом,

муж советуется с женою, как с другом, а не как с прислужницею.

2) Сравнительный оборот часто ВСТУПАЕТ В ОДНОРОДНЫЕ ОТНОШЕНИЯ с другими обстоятельствами:

общался с ним на равных, как с другом,

поговорить  по душам, как с другом

откровенно… именно как с другом,

все обходились с ним, как с другом, как с братом, откровенно, даже нежно,

был с ним искренен, как с другом,

буду говорить просто, как с другом.

3) Значение ЕДИНИЧНОГО ОБОРОТА соответствует следующим синонимичным выражениям: искренне, откровенно, нежно, просто, по душам. В этих случаях,  выражая эти признаковые значения, он обычно обособляется.